# Getting fb friends likes with "Friends" privacy in Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Earlier to get my facebook friends "likes" I used such requests to graph API:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<friend_id>?fields=likes.fields(created_time,id,name,category)&access_token=?

https://graph.facebook.com/<friend_id>/likes?fields=created_time,id,name,category&access_token=?
```

Now for about two weeks I can't do it if my friends "likes" are not "Public" (such as "Friends", "Only me", etc.).
And these requests return only "likes" with "Public" privacy.

Can you give any advice how to solve this problem ?
Maybe I should set some special options for my application ?

Comment: If non-public likes are available *at all* you'll need authenticate your app in such a way that it can make requests for such data on behalf of the user.

Comment: Maybe they are not longer your friends. The Graph API always works only with the permissions the token has, so the users have to give that kind of permission to the app.

Comment: Maybe it is related to new [Graph Search](http://news.cnet.com/8301-1023_3-57564077-93/facebook-takes-on-google-with-graph-search/)...