# Facebook Graph Api: get friend's -> likes privacy setting (visibility)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

You can make a request to the facebook's graph API and retrieve your friends, their likes and many other information.

I'm a looking for a way to retrieve exclusive information. I want to check which of my friends are having their likes on "friends" privacy. A user can set his likes to be visible to the "public", to "friends", "only him/her" and other options. I want to learn how to retrieve my friends privacy options on their likes.

A similar question is this: [Getting fb friends likes with "Friends" privacy in Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14654466/getting-fb-friends-likes-with-friends-privacy-in-graph-api)

Thanks,
Orestes

Comment: Getting your friends and their likes have been removed in API v2.0. And v1.0 will only exists until 4/30/2015 so I wouldn't build anything on top of it

Comment: I'm making a research and I just wanna learn how common is to have your likes hidden. I'm running on v1 and it doesn't affect me in the future as I wanna figure it out now. Thanks for the information though!